# Solving 8x8 Recursive Knight Tour in Python

Tags: python, recursion, knights-tour

**Problem Explanation**

I wanted to create a Knight's Tour in an 8x8 board and only used recursion to implement the code thus far.

The knight tour for an 8x8 board has around 19 quadrillion moves.

src = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour#Number_of_tours

My perspective is that even if it reaches a square where it can no longer make a move it can move back recursively to find a solution every time without terminating.

I use 2 lists, solution_list - that stores the solution of the tour
and pos_visited - that stores the positions previously visited, which don't have further possible moves.

**Error**

This question [Knight's Tour in Python - Getting Path from Predecessors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61245303/knights-tour-in-python-getting-path-from-predecessors) helped me to figure out where I went wrong.

Initially, there is no problem in moving to a previous position but as the list pos_visited grows the function **Next_move**, therefore, can't pick a move from move_set which has no moves and throws 'IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence'.

I have only added the necessary code and relative functions for readability.

```py
import random


def Start_Tour(board, solution_list, move_set, pos_visited):
    # clears board
    clear_board(board, solution_list, move_set, pos_visited)

    # ASKS STARTING POSITION
    print("Give initial coordinates to start: ")
    x_initial, y_initial = first_pos(board)
    board[x_initial][y_initial] = "♘"

    # Displays board
    display_board(board)

    solution_list.append([x_initial, y_initial])
    print(f"Starting position defined at {x_initial, y_initial}")
    count = 0

    while count < 65:

        # Move_set gets valid and unoccupied coordinates in board
        move_set = potential_moves(x_initial, y_initial, board)

        # check if move_set is empty
        if len(move_set) == 0:
            # BACKTRACK if empty
            print("Moving Back")
            retrack(board, solution_list, pos_visited)

        # Else-Place Knight
        else:

            # choose one move as xn,yn at random
            xn, yn = Next_move(move_set, pos_visited)

            # place marker in xn,yn
            board[xn][yn] = "♘"

            # clears previous position
            clear_previous_pos(board, solution_list)

            # adds position to solution_list
            solution_list.append([xn, yn])
            print(f"\n solution_list -> {solution_list}")
            print("\n")

            # displays board
            display_board(board)

            # sets x_initial and y_initial for generating next set of potential moves
            x_initial = xn
            y_initial = yn
            count += 1
            print(f"\n {count}")


def potential_moves(a, b, board):
    """
    Takes current position of knight(a,b) and generates possible moves as a list
    """
    move_set = [
        [a - 1, b - 2],
        [a - 2, b - 1],
        [a - 2, b + 1],
        [a - 1, b + 2],
        [a + 1, b + 2],
        [a + 2, b + 1],
        [a + 2, b - 1],
        [a + 1, b - 2],
    ]
    for x, y in move_set[:]:
        if x in range(0, 8) and y in range(0, 8) and board[x][y] == " ":
            pass
        else:
            move_set.remove([x, y])

    return move_set


def retrack(board, solution_list, pos_visited):
    """
    helps knight to move back to previous position.
    """
    x_current, y_current = solution_list.pop(-1)  # x,y have no more valid moves
    pos_visited.append([x_current, y_current])  # adds x,y to positions already visited
    board[x_current][y_current] = " "  # erases current x,y pos'n
    x, y = solution_list[-1]  # returns pos'n before getting stuck
    if len(potential_moves(x, y, board)) != 0 and [x, y] not in pos_visited:
        return x, y
    else:
        return retrack(board, solution_list, pos_visited)


def Next_move(move_set, pos_visited):
    """
    returns a move at random from move_set if it isn't visited already.
    """
    xn, yn = random.choice(move_set)
    if positions_visited(xn, yn, pos_visited):
        return xn, yn
    else:
        move_set.remove([xn, yn])
        move_set1 = move_set
        return Next_move(move_set, pos_visited)


def positions_visited(n1, n2, pos_visited):  # Checks for position in tracker
    """
    checks if position has been visited already
    """
    if [n1, n2] in pos_visited:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

[This is the output I get so far before an error is thrown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiHK5.png)

P.S: I've been learning python for 2 months now and don't know much about algorithms yet. I first would like to arrive at a solution with a basic approach before trying to use algorithms. It will be very helpful if you could explain in detail if you think I should take a different approach to this.

Thank you

-Santosh

Edit: I have added the traceback error

```py
    
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    IndexError    Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-22-aba4d6ed48dc> in <module>
    ----> 1 Start_Tour(cb,solution_list,move_set,pos_visited)
          
    <ipython-input-18-0c959cf546f8> in Start_Tour(board, solution_list, 
    move_set, pos_visited)
          31   
          32         # choose one move as xn,yn
    ----> 33             xn,yn = Next_move(move_set,pos_visited)
          34 
          35         #place marker in xn,yn
          
    <ipython-input-21-c2489e88fd1e> in Next_move(move_set, pos_visited)
          9         move_set.remove([xn,yn])
          10         move_set1 = move_set
     ---> 11         return Next_move(move_set,pos_visited)

    <ipython-input-21-c2489e88fd1e> in Next_move(move_set, pos_visited)
          3     #returns a move at random from move_set if it isn't visited already.
    ----> 4     xn,yn = random.choice(move_set)
          5     if positions_visited(xn,yn,pos_visited):
          6         return xn,yn
          
    F:\Anaconda\lib\random.py in choice(self, sea)
          259             i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
          260         except ValueError:
      --> 261             raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty 
sequence') from None
          262         return seq[i]
          263 

    IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
```

Comment: Post your traceback error that appeared in the console.

Comment: You could compare your code to the following described [Knight tour algorithm & code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/the-knights-tour-problem-backtracking-1/) based upon recursion and backtracking.

Comment: In `retrack` function, the `cb` variable is not defined.

Comment: @Pokebab I have added the traceback error message.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE Thank you, the `cb` variable was defined globally as a nested list so the code did run nevertheless. I have edited the `retrack` function with the argument `board` instead of `cb`.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your problem lies in this code here. It's obviously not populating your move_set list for some reason. I.E what's happening is that the `else` part of your `for` loop is being executed for every possible move. Which makes sense because judging by your board, there is no possible moves for the knight to make. Each `board[x][y]` does not equal `' '`.

```
def potential_moves(a,b,board):
    '''
    Takes current position of knight(a,b) and generates possible moves as a list
    '''
    move_set = [[a-1,b-2],[a-2,b-1],[a-2,b+1],[a-1,b+2],[a+1,b+2],[a+2,b+1],[a+2,b-1],[a+1,b-2]]
    for x,y in move_set[:]:
      if x in range(0,8) and y in range(0,8) and board[x][y]==' ':
         pass 
      else:
         move_set.remove([x,y])
    
    return move_set
```

Edit: As has been pointed out by the comments on your post. It looks like the knight has no moves to make because of `cb` is not defined in your `retrack` function, which I assume is meant to prevent the knight from having no possible moves.